# Copying file uploaded vai PHP's HTTP Get in PHP 4

Tags: php, ajax, http, file-upload, php4

I have been working on adding functionality to a site originally written in PHP 4.4.9. It's not in their budget to port the site to PHP5, so don't even suggest it. (Although it needs it badly). The problem I am facing is how to copy binary data from a GET request to a file location on the server. The code that is currently written to support this method is as follows:

```
function save($path) { 
    $input = fopen("php://input", "r");
    $temp = tmpfile();
    $realSize = stream_copy_to_stream($input, $temp);
    fclose($input);

    if ($realSize != $this->getSize()){            
        return false;
    }

    $target = fopen($path, "w");        
    fseek($temp, 0, SEEK_SET);
    stream_copy_to_stream($temp, $target);
    fclose($target);
}
```

The problem that I am having with this is the funciton `stream_copy_to_stream` is only supported in PHP 5. Here is what I have so far, but it seems to only create files that are 8K in size and I'm not sure why. It should, in theory, allow for up to 20M.

```
function save($path) {    
    $input = fopen("php://input", "rb");
    $temp = tmpfile();
    fwrite($temp, fread($input, 20971520));
    fclose($input);

    $target = fopen($path, "w");        
    fseek($temp, 0, SEEK_SET);
    #stream_copy_to_stream($temp, $target);
    fwrite($target, fread($temp, 20971520));
    fclose($target);
    echo $path;

    return true;
}
```

I removed the size check because I couldn't figure a way to get the filesize when reading. Any help is greatly appreciated on this. I have been racking my brain for literally hours and I know there is someone out there, most likely on stackoverflow, that can answer my question probably very easily.

Thanks for all the help in advance!

Also, I am submitting data via GET to to allow multiple file uploads with progress bars, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came across this thread looking for answer for exact same problem.
I know post is old but putting answer here for anyone else looking.
You were close.
fread only takes [8192 byte chunks](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php) out of stream at a time. So you will have to loop through until it sees end of file.

```
    function save($path) {    
        $input = fopen("php://input", "rb");
        $temp = tmpfile();
        while(!feof($input))
            fwrite($temp, fread($input, 8192));
        //fwrite($temp, fread($input, 20971520));
        fclose($input);

        $target = fopen($path, "w");        
        fseek($temp, 0, SEEK_SET);
        #stream_copy_to_stream($temp, $target);
        while(!feof($temp))
            fwrite($target, fread($temp, 8192));

        fclose($target);
        echo $path;

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: man, I wish I had figured that out earlier...lol. I ended up using a different method of posting the image, but thanks for the reply! This might help some other poor soul working with a PHP 4.